# Wildcard subdomain redirect to a subfolder in Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I'm using Route53 for my DNS. I was wondering how to redirect all with subdomains to a subfolder of my web app.

```
test.example.com -> test.example.com/folder
abc.example.com -> abc.example.com/folder
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: This isn't done in DNS, it's done on your web server or front-end proxy if you have one.  What web server are you using -- S3?  Also, it seems a fair question to ask why you would want to do this.

Comment: My bad, you're right. This isn't done in DNS. I already solved it with my router. @Michael-sqlbot